# php vendor\bin\phpunit is printing in console a text

Tags: php, testing, tdd, phpunit

I have been trying to use PHPUnit to test my app, (I installed it via Composer) but when I was trying to execute the tests that I have in my directory called "Tests" in this way:

@myappsite$:php vendor\bin\phpunit Tests

It just printed the content of vendor\bin\**phpunit** :

```
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../phpunit/phpunit"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/phpunit"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

Somebody that has ran into this problem before and can help me please. Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, The only problem was with **php** command, It's not necessary because is not calling a php file but a .bat file. So the thing I gotta do was:

```
@myappsite$:vendor\bin\phpunit Tests
```

And it itself runs the php command. I posted this for anybody who maybe has the same problem.

Comment: verify this answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the script is not a php but a bash script, what PHPUnit version is that you were installing..? i.e. what is your composer.json?

Comment: Thank you for answering. The PHPUnit's version is 4.1.1 and this is my composer.json:

    {
        "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*@dev"
    }
}

Comment: That's probably it, the script seems to be a unix shell script... maybe try this: 
`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit Tests`

Comment: Yes man, That's what I did and worked perfectly. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt I wrote `phpunit` instead of `php vendor\bin\phpunit` and got result.

Comment: This seems to work, but for some reason it will give problems with finding classes afterwards.