# Why phpUnit test does not work? ZF2

Tags: php, bash, zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am reading the book "Learn ZF2: Learning By Example" by Slavey Karadzhov. Now I am at pages 103-107. I am trying to run PHPUnit test as described, but nothing happens... **Where is the problem and how to fix it?**

To go into the same situation you would have to:

```
git clone https://github.com/slaff/learnzf2.git .

composer.phar self-update
composer.phar install

git stash
git checkout 'ch-unittest'
```

This should bring you the same files as I have (=as in the book).

Now, I try to run this command:

```
ZF2_PATH=`pwd`/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library \php vendor/bin/phpunit -c module/User/tests/
```

And the command does not work as expected...
I would expect some test result output or so, but all I get is the output witch is similar to the content I have in `vendor/bin/phpunit` file. It is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/phpunit"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

To be more precise, the first line (#!/usr/bin/env sh) does not show up in the output. The rest do show up.

**

I am running the code on Windows 8.1 Pro OS, using Git Bash (git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1). `php` keyword seems to work well as writing `php -v` works as expected (outputs `PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2014 11:20:58) ...`)

My own guess would be that Git bash cannot resolve the code it finds in vendor/bin/phpunit so it fails there... But this is the guess only...

**EDIT #1:**
Just tried on shared hosting with LAMP set. Everything went fine. It seems that Zend Framework 2 and Windows are not so friendly at some points (e.g. at the just mentioned unit testing case). Looks like the very good book (no sarcasm, it is really the good one) would be better if it would have one more chapter on something like VirtualBox + Vagrant + PuPHPet (or something close to that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of composer.json file used in the book: `phpunit/phpunit" : "3.7.*`

I have changed `phpunit/phpunit" : "3.7.*` to `phpunit/phpunit" : "4.5.*` as 4.5 version of PHPUnit is the current stable.
Then, of course: `php composer.phar update`
Then this one will work nicely:

```
ZF2_PATH=`pwd`/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library \php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c module/User/tests/
```

The command above is not the same as in the book.

Tested on Windows 8.1, Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS x64, the isolated development environment provide [here](https://github.com/slaff/learnzf2-box). Works well.

There is also a way to make PHPUnit 3.7.* work on all systems (same systems tested by me), but the command must be changed to:

```
ZF2_PATH=`pwd`/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library \php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit -c module/User/tests/
```

The command above is not the same as in the book.

So... Here we have two ways mentioned to go with PHPUnit tests to make them work. It is up to us to decide witch of two is better. I would prefer the one with increasing PHPUnit version to 4.5 at the moment.

Many thanks go to Slavey Karadzhov - the author of the book who made isolated development environment for programming with Zend Framework 2(ZF2) available. 
Also, thanks to @jamaldo, @steeler and @malte whose activity (post, comments) brought me on the right track. The post I am talking about is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881289/php-vendor-bin-phpunit-is-printing-in-console-a-text](http://@jamaldo,%20@steeler%20and%20@malte%20whose%20activity%20brought%20me%20on%20the%20right%20track.%20The%20post%20I%20am%20talking%20about%20is%20here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881289/php-vendor-bin-phpunit-is-printing-in-console-a-text)